Additional live wire on new cooktop?
Attempting a simple cooktop replacement.  Old cooktop has 3 wires (live, neutral, earth) hardwired into corresponding wall wires. New cooktop has 2 live wires, so 4 wires in total.  The circuit for the cooktop is 20amp.  My instinct is to combine the 2 live wires and connect to wall as usual.  Is this correct?

Refer to The Fabulous Manual rather than guessing. If it came from some far off shore without  a Fabulous Manual in your local language and a listing from a Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory local to your country or region, send it back before it burns your house down. CE is not a testing laboratory mark.

Can you please post photos of the wall box the old cooktop was hooked up to?

It may be a stove, like mine, that has 2 lives, 1 neural and 1 earth (or ground). These are designed for use on a 3phase supply, only using 2 of the 3 phases. You need to check.

@nobody Live, Neutral, Earth in the question is a very strong clue that this  is not the US.

Are we in an RV/caravan or in a 230V country e.g. Europe?
